# Taking Adobe Flash Player Off Its Leash on WinXP

Tags: windows, flash

I'm working with a flash application that runs as a standalone executable by way of the File -> Create Projector... option on the standalone Adobe Flash Player.  I've noticed that it's pretty well-behaved, with a modest memory footprint and reasonable CPU demands, even when it's struggling with something difficult to render or animate for some reason.

Is there any way to make it NOT be well-behaved?  The computers I'll be deploying this thing on (WinXP machines) EXIST to run this application; it can gobble up as much memory or CPU cycles as it damn well pleases.  And if it would make the animations a bit smoother, I'd actually prefer it do so.

Any tips for inviting this thing to hog as much memory/processing power as it wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can turn up framerate to max, as well as quality ... but high quality is the default ... higher framerates will make animations smoother ... and also consume CPU of course ...

other than that, feel free to rotate pixel data, apply many filters, gradient mask and use transparency and different blendmodes ... and animate as much as possible ... :D

but really, framerate is the only thing i can really think of, that lets the player use more resources, with the same app ...

greetz

back2dos